# Winter Bash 2014: It's time for hats again!

Tags: discussion, hats

### It's almost time for Winter Bash 2014!

The last couple years, Stack Exchange has run a holiday event called [Winter Bash](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash)!  It's a fun little event where users collect "hats" that you can wear on your avatars by doing various things (post on a certain day, get a question to a certain score, and things like that).

Each year, they ask us if we'd like to participate.  And in both 2012 and 2013, we had a lot of fun with it, so I'm assuming we'll want to participate again this year! :-)  The event will start on December 15, 2014, and it'll run until January 4, 2015.  After that, the hats we've earned will all disappear.

So what do you say?  **Do we want hats again?**  Feel free to vote on this post or leave feedback in the form of a comment or reply!

***Note:** users who don't want to see hats will be able to click a button labeled "I hate hats".*

Comment: Do we want hats again? >> はいはい～ <3

Comment: Will be my first hats on JL. Yes, I want it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everyone seems positive, so we're getting hats again!

*Yippee!*